# How does call stack work with recursion with or without return type?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, return-type, callstack

I noticed that some recursions have a return type but some are just having void as the return type. I can't tell when to use which. I also looked into the call stack and I guess the recursions with a 'void' type is just returning the value recorded on the stack. I don't know if my understanding is correct.
I can't convert a recursion with void return type into a recursion a return type. For example, I don't know how to implement the Fibonacci function with the void return type.

```
private int fibonacci(int number) {

            if (number < 1) {
                return number;
            }
            return fibonacci(number-1)+fibonacci(number-2);
        }
```

Also, in the rec function, I investigated the call stack; but I can't tell how does the program knows when to pop a record on the stack. In the base case of the rec function, the program works perfectly fine without the 'return;'; but I noticed that it also works with the 'return;'. I really can't tell why it is like this. Can someone please explain how does the stack work with the recursion?

```
private static void rec(int l, int r, List<String> list,String s){
        if(r==0){
            list.add(s);
//            return;
        }

        if(l>0){
            rec(l-1,r,list,s+"(");
        }
        if(r>l){
            rec(l,r-1,list, s+")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with recursion. Ask yourself one question: does my function need to return any value? If yes then you indeed return some value, otherwise you don't... Don't complicate things.

Comment: And you code a 'return' in a void function when you want to terminate execution of this instance of the routine without running until the end of the text of the routine.  In the example, the 'return' prevents the execution of the 'l>0' case.  Does that matter to your code? Only you know.

Comment: Why does 'rec()` work with and without the call to `return;`? The `return;` would end the method right away while without it the conditions `l > 0` and `r > l` would still be evaluated and those would evaluate to false in the `r=0` case.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for explaining! So can I understand the return as triggering it to popping the entire function from the stack?

Comment: Also, if I want to record every Fibonacci Number in sequence, like [0,1,1,2,3,5], I think I have to record the returned number of each call; but if I return it then there is no chance for me to record it as the result is directly returned. If I don't return an int then I can't add an int onto an ArrayList. I don't know if I should return in this case. Is there a way to extract the value on the stack and put it into my array?